# Getitem alternative in python 2.7

Tags: python, getter

I am a beginner in python and I am testing some scripts.
My question is if _getitem__ syntax for python has always the same parameters(index). 
Lets say I have this code

```
class VagueTuple:
    def __init__(self, cont):
        self.cont = cont
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.cont[index]

vague_list = VagueTuple((("A", "B"), ("C", "D",)))

print(vague_list[1][0])
print(vague_list[1][1])
```

This is a normal getitem usage in python.
Is there a way to implement the following instead? How should the getitem be then?

```
print vague_list[1, 0], vague_list[1, 1] = ("C","D")
```

I tried to replace "index" of getitem method with rows and columns of my list but there is an error apparently

Comment: If you use `[1,0]` then the index argument to `__getitem__` will be the tuple `(1,0)`

Comment: This already works, `__getitem__` is passed a *tuple* of elements. You can even accept a sequence of slices.

Comment: No it does not. I get this error TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: @GeoF: you do need to properly translate that tuple passed to `VagueTuple` into separate index operations on your `cont` attribute.

Comment: And you should always include any errors you get in your question, with the full traceback.

Comment: `ob = self.cont`, `for i in index: ob = ob[i]` and `return ob`.

Comment: That assumes that `index` will always be a tuple of indices.

Comment: Thanks my error is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File testttt.py, line 10, in <module>
    print vague_list[1, 0], vague_list[1, 1]
  File testttt.py, line 5, in __getitem__
    return self.cont[index]
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: Ok I found a solution to this `def __getitem__(self, (x,y)):
        return self.cont[x][y]`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `object[1,0]` then the index argument to `object.__getitem__` will be the tuple `(1,0)`

```
class Foo:
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        print(index)

Foo()[1,2]
```

prints

```
(1, 2)
```